# Spring WebServiceOperations, how to override the HostnameVerify?

Tags: spring, web-services

I have an autowired org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceOperations on which I call the marshallSendAndReceive(url, requestPayload) method.

When the service url is a local one, the call is successful. When I change it to one of our test machines I get:

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching myservername found.;
nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching myservername found.
```

I've read on similar questions that I need to override the HostnameVerify to no longer verify the host name, which would suffice as this is just a dev temporary test. How can that be done?

Answer (score 3):

I achieved what I wanted with the following. In the spring xml, the actual class for my object was:

org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate

So you can instantiate this and fill out the following to do the override.

```
WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate();
HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender sender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
sender.setHostnameVerifier(new NullHostnameVerifier());
template.setMessageSender(sender);



public class NullHostnameVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
}
```